# /usr/local/sbin/oxenstored: error while loading shared libraries: libxenctrl.so.4.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt

I've just compiled xen 4.14 from source on ubuntu 20.10. The compilation didn't produce errors. But then,when I ran this command :

```
root@zio-z390aoruspro:/etc/xen# sudo /etc/init.d/xencommons start
```

this is what happened :

```
Starting /usr/local/sbin/oxenstored.../usr/local/sbin/oxenstored: error while loading shared libraries: libxenctrl.so.4.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Setting domain 0 name, domid and JSON config...

/usr/local/lib/xen/bin/xen-init-dom0: error while loading shared libraries: libxenctrl.so.4.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Starting xenconsoled...

/usr/local/sbin/xenconsoled: error while loading shared libraries: libxenctrl.so.4.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Starting QEMU as disk backend for dom0

/usr/local/lib/xen/bin/qemu-system-i386: error while loading shared libraries: libxenctrl.so.4.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to fix it. After several tries,I asked what to do,before to damage the system.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with:

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```